# How to get array of fonts contained in an NSFontCollection?

Tags: nsfont, nsfontmanager

How can you get an `NSArray` of fonts or fontfamilies that are "contained" by an `NSFontCollection`?

All `NSFont` and `NSFontManager` methods seem to require a single `NSFontDescriptor`, while `NSFontCollection` returns an `NSArray` of `NSFontDescriptor` objects. It seems like there should be a method that returns fonts matching these.

Is it necessary to query each font descriptor against all fonts manually?

Answer (score 1):

You can get the font collection's `matchingDescriptors` (an array of `NSFontDescriptor`) and ask each descriptor for its `-objectForKey:NSFontFamilyAttribute`, and dump them (strings) into a set to unique them.

Alternatively you can turn each font descriptor into a font (by creating a font with the descriptor) and ask for its `familyName` (and then unique those).

Both of these methods are fairly straightforward with Swift's `compactMap()` (to discard `nil`s).

Comment: Interesting. I'll have to give this a look. It might even be worth trying with NSArray KVC operators on `valueForKeyPath:`

Answer (score -1):

```
NSArray *familyNames = [[NSFontManager sharedFontManager] availableFontFamilies];
```

Comment: Sorry that doesn't do what I am asking.